# ninject error for Ninject.ActivationException

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I have ASP.NET Web Application and added dll to the project.
I glue it I chose Ninject Ioc.

Because Web Application must have default constructor I decided to glue it in following way:

```
public IPlayerDb PlayerDb { get; set; }

public Logon()
{
     Global.Kernel.Inject(this);
}
```

IPlayerDb is in external DLL library 'Contracts.dll'
PlayerDb class implemented IPlayerDb is in other dll : 'DataAccess.dll'

In DataAccess.dll there is class making glueing :

```
public class Bindings : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IDbConfig>().To<DbConfig>();
        Bind<IPlayerDb>().To<PlayerDb>();
    }
}
```

It's OK when I use my project after Visual Studio restarts (and IIS express I guess also).
But if I start to debug the application again it makes me following Error Message:

**Error activating IPlayerDb
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
Activation path:
  2) Injection of dependency IPlayerDb into property PlayerDb of type Logon
  1) Request for logon_aspx
An exception of type 'Ninject.ActivationException' occurred in Ninject.dll but was not handled in user code**

So, what's wrong with it. Seems I did everything by manual. Advice needed.

Comment: oh ok i don't know about the Web Forms lifecycle and dependency resolution. Since the issue occurs only when debugging and it states that a binding is missing, the issue is most likely still with integration of ninject into your application. You're most likely creating multiple kernels and not initializing it the correct way (initializing => creating bindings / loading modules). Otherwise there would be no possibility to have a kernel which is missing the binding for `IPlayerDb`.

Comment: Sure I know there is an issue here. But I did it all by manual. SO manual is buggy

Comment: I found the core of the problem:
private static IKernel CreateKernel() returns not all dll loaded to my application